# preinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 - ubiquity crashes on first boot when installing packets

Tags: system-installation, ubiquity, preinstallation

I just received a Dell Latitude 5480 with Ubuntu 16.04 preinstalled. At first boot an installation program is started, and after some questions (language, license, timezone, keyboard, username, recovery media), it fails when trying to download packages (as shown by the main window of the installer which says (the french equivalent of) `Downloading package 1 of 12`.

The error window says that (French equivalent of)

```
An error occured when installing packages: 
"Command '[debconf-apt-progress','-','apt-get','-y','install',...]' 
returned non-zero exit status 255"
```

(where ... is a list of 22 packets)

```
The following packages are broken: 

Maybe the image of the installer is too old or some of the packets listed 
have a bug. Take a look in /var/log/syslog.
```

but I can't! I've no access to the normal system!

So, my questions are:

- Is it possible to avoid this downloading or installing step in the installer? (I tried without network, with WiFi or a wired connection, it's the same)
- more generally, does somebody have a workaround for this problem?

Comment: it iis possible to download an installer image and extract ti to the HDD. the only issue would be if there are non generic drivers supplied with the installer on your computer.

Comment: Where should I put this image? As far as I could see by booting my preinstalled ubuntu in recovery mode, I have a complete system installed on disk, not a iso image. I just have to run the initial configuration without crashes...

Comment: you have to extract the image (unpack it), if it is fully installed, then perhaps the repositories need to be corrected.

Comment: Oh yes, the repos maybe the point. Good idea! In recovery mode, granting access to the disk and to the network, I managed to run an "apt-get upgrade" after replacing "/etc/apt/sources.list" by  "/etc/apt/sources.list.ubuntu" that was also present on my system... I will post an answer if it works...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from a bad configuration of the software sources in the preinstalled system provided by Dell.

The correct list of repositories was present in the file `sources.list.ubuntu` in `/etc/apt` , but the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` pointed on an installation CD, not available for the end-user.

To correct the problem:

- restart your system (after the installer fails), choose "*Advanced options for Ubuntu* " in the grub menu then the latest linux kernel in "*Recovery mode* ", then "*root* " to get a console with administration rights.
- type the following commands:

   `mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.as_received
   mv /etc/apt/sources.list.ubuntu /etc/apt/sources.list
   exit`

Then choose "*resume* " from the recovery menu, the installer will now finish its work!

Thanks to *revery*  to suggest looking at repositories!